# What's a 调警? (In a Command Center (指挥中心))

Tags: translation

指挥中心里头的调警是什么？

调警 in a Command Center is what kind of policeman?

What is its English equivalent?

Often seen like this: *指挥中心调警称*....

Comment: Never heard that. Could you give some relevant context?

Comment: googling 异地调警 yields ２ news items， one about 12月1日，铜川市公安局， the other about ９月２日,哈尔滨调警用直升机搜捕三逃犯。 In both 异地调警   seems to refer not to any type of police officer but to the transfer of police (forces) from another place.

Comment: IMO, it's `调警(diaojing)`, means `transfer policeman temporarily for a specific task`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three possibilities:

1) 调警 as an internal police term

Examples:

- ... 指令通过光纤迅速传递到消防大队、派出所、交警中队等处警单位，提高了**调警**速度和准确性。
- 通过110快速**调警**处置，成功抓获现行违法犯罪嫌疑人91人、救助群众165人

In this context, it means "dispatch"(like 911 dispatch).

It is rarely used outside of police force. So civilians rarely heard of it and may consider it as a wrong word.

2） You split the sentence wrong

Examples:

- 哈尔滨调*警用直升机*搜捕三逃犯

It is short for 调用, meaning "make use of". Because 警用直升机(police helicopter) also has a 用 in it, omitting the 用 in 调用 would make the sentence less redundant.

3) Short for 调用警力(transfer police force)

Examples:

- 采用异地**调警**的方式分别从虹桥分局....

Answer (score 2):

It is not noun, not a kind of policeman.
It is abbreviation of "调度警察" or "调度警力", which means dispatch police forces, facilities from one site/place to another to support their emergent needs.

调度-- dispatch,schedule,coordinate
警察-- Police
警力-- Police Force

google "指挥中心调警称", you may see news like "特勤中队接到指挥中心调警称:“blablabla” ", it means that the special service lochus received command saying that "blablabla" from command center to dispatch them.